# CSS won't apply to HTML code in to-be-placed-variable with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got some HTML code to be placed with a button with .innerHTML but CSS behaves weird. When I try to apply CSS to the ID #herpderp it won't do anything nor affect the selector descendants at all.

When I look at the site with chrome developer tools the elements are properly nested. If the #herpderp can't be changed that way then why do global selectors like img and p change? and what is a better way to apply CSS since I dont want to use inline styling nor global selectors like img, p and section?

Any critism is welcome.

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
 <a onclick="changeContent(0)" href="#herpDerp">TEST AREA</a>
</div>

<div id='background'>
  <div id=mainContent>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function changeContent(link) {
switch (link) {
    case 0:
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = herpDerp;
        break;
    }
}

var herpDerp = '<section id=\"herpDerp\">' +
                   "<h1>BLAHBLAH</h1> " +
                   "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>" +
                   "<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.</p>" +
                   "<p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>"+
                   '<img src=\"img/foto.jpg\" alt="photo">' +
                "</section>";
```

CSS ~ doesnt work

```
#herpDerp, #herpDerp img, #herpDerp p {
   font-size: 5rem;
   visibility: hidden;
   background-color: #F00;
}
```

CSS ~ does work

```
img { 
  display: none;
}

p {
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: Are you mixing double `"` and single `'` quotes in your concatenation?(_you certainly are_)

Comment: Look at the id.... You have `<section id="#herpDerp">` and it **MUST** be `<section id="herpDerp">`. The `#` is only used on css to match an element with the given id (e.g.: `#abc` matches `<a id="abc">`).

Comment: I know of the need for backslash when double and signle quotes are used, but thats not the problems here. I'll edit it

Comment: plus, what is 5 'rem'? should be 'em' isn't it. AND if you set display: none; then why put visibility: hidden; after? visibility: hidden; won't have any effect then

Comment: @Ismael Miguel Ah stupid mistake lol, changed but didnt fix it.

Comment: @Shiji.Jiang rem is different than em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: @shadryck You give me a lesson :)

Comment: @Shiji.Jiang Upon search, I've noticed that I was incorrect. `rem` is a valid unit. `rem` is the same as `em`, but based on the root element instead of the parent.

Comment: @Shiji.Jiang I personally hate em, when you nest multiple divs the em will scale with it so things can become confusing haha, there is always something to learn.

Comment: Can you assemble a stack snippet showing the problem?

Comment: @Ismael Miguel Alright, give me a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section #herpDerp is dynamically created using javascript.
If you want to style the elements within that section, use an enclosing div to select the elements.

Eg:

```
#content h1{
    color: red;
   font-size: 5rem;
}
```

You can also specify the styling information in the javascript itself. But in my opinion, the above method is better as it separates styling from implementation.

Check this : 
https://jsfiddle.net/3brtfto4/